# Changing name if already exsist

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

> jQuery.filer-1.0.5

for images upload.
The problem is i have some other data to send when uploading image and add to database also i need to change the name of image if already exists and add it in folder.
i try to implement data in this part

```
uploadFile: {
        url: "./php/upload.php",
        data: {ID: $("#ID).val()},
```

But it skip it and not capturing this value how can i achieve what i want.
I was able to save the image in database i added the query in upload.php after

```
if($data['isComplete']){
   //query
```

That's the farest way i could get i need to save value so on delete image i can delete this specific image because if i delete based on name some images with the same will all be deleted.
I tried to use

```
$lastid =$mysqli->insert_id;
```

but in multi images all i can get is the last id and i cannot access the previous images

any idea ?

Comment: Well 25 times viewed and no answer is it too difficult to users , if it's the case tell me to leave and find another source of help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your [php-upload](https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader) to v0.3.

Now you just set in options `'replace'=> false` and the script will automatically add (1), (2)... at the end of file name to prevent the replacing.